# Nav change background on slide active

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to be able to change my header background dynamically depending on which slide comes up. Each slide is pulling in a post from a cms, each of those posts have an option to add a background image or not. The ones with a background image have a div class of "intro-bg" ones that don't do not have that class. Essentially I want my header to be transparent when the ones with a background image are active slides, and then go back to normal with slides that do not have that class are active. Right now the code below makes the first part happen, but not the second part. The header background does not change after the next slide. I hope this all makes sense, below is my code I am not sure what is going wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$('.fade-carousel').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
     if ($('.slick-active .slide-container div').hasClass('intro-bg')) {
         $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
     } else {
         $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: sure give me one second. Its built in statamic CMS so the language is different than standard HTML

Comment: Here is a codepen showing the issue, as you can see, it works on the init, and the next slide as they both have the intro-bg class. After that the next slide does not, yet it does not remove the "transparent-header" class. Let me know if this makes sense:  https://codepen.io/ascarb1/pen/MQJzqW

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
        $(".fade-carousel").slick({
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand', // ondemand progressive anticipated
            infinite: true
        });
        // On before slide change
        $('.fade-carousel').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            var nextSlide = parseInt(nextSlide)+1;
            if($( ".fade-carousel .slide-container:nth-child("+nextSlide+") > div").hasClass('intro-bg')) { 
                $('#header').addClass('transparent-header'); 
            } else { 
                $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header'); 
            } 
        });
    });
```

[Ref Link](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings)

Comment: Thank you for responding!! It did not work. I get "unexpected token ." as a console error. I tried removing it, but I get different errors after that.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check the classes before applying (fade-carousel, slick-slide etc). If still not working, you should post the full code.

Comment: Thanks! I updated with the div where the class "intro-bg" would be. No console errors, but it prevents my slider from sliding now.

`  $('.fade-carousel').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var nextSlide = parseInt(nextSlide)+1;
      if($( ".slide-container div("+nextSlide+")").hasClass('intro-bg')) {
             $('#header').addClass('transparent-header');
         } else {
             $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
         }
    });`

Comment: You are missing something  I guess. Please post your full HTML structure.

Comment: You should keep ':nth-child' . Why removed it?

Comment: I just updated, and it no longer breaks my slider, but it does not work. I must be missing something. here is a codepen showing the example: codepen.io/ascarb1/pen/MQJzqW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164817/discussion-between-estin-sunny-and-aarons).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this answer on a different post, but this works:

```
$('.fade-carousel').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
 if ($('.slide-container:eq('+nextSlide+') > div').hasClass('intro-bg')) {
     $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
 } else {
     $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
 }
```

});